# New graphics card not rendering anything

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

I just bought a new GTX 970 and ive tried to render some scenes I had to test the performance but everything I render with my GPU comes out blank, just transparent. If I switch over and render a scene with my CPU it renders fine, so I could really use some help with finding a solution to my problem.

Comment: generally hardware problems are off-topic but in case someone would answer you'll have to add at least your OS , blender version

Comment: Sorry, its my first time using this forum. My os is Win7 64 bit. I am running Blender 2.71

Comment: @Weirdybeardyman update your blender

Comment: Always make sure an issue persists for several versions before calling it officially a bug. Notice that several things can cause a transparent render, from old graphics drivers to memory overload.

Comment: @Weirdybeardyman Your GPU is supported from version 2.73 http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.73/Cycles

Comment: Thanks, I feel pretty dumb, I completely forgot I didn't have the most recent version of blender. It works fine now :D

Answer (score 3):

As it shows in [Blender Release notes](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.73/Cycles), GTX 9xx series are supported from version 2.73.